# Monotonicity in Knuth Optimization

Tags: algorithm

I'm in the middle of learning what is *Knuth Optimization*.

The relevant information can be accessed through [here](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/8219)

Basically, there are two assumption in *Knuth Optimization*.

One is **Quadrangle Inequality** and the other is **Monotonicity**

I can totally understand what is **Quadrangle Inequality**. However, cause there is no examples explaining about **Monotoniciy**, I can't get it.

***Monotonicity*** : *C[b][c] < C[a][d] (a, b, c, d)*

As far as I know, the **Monotonicity** is kinda linear feature and if there are two different element(b, c) in between the elements(a, d) outside of them, the cost in range b to c is smaller than the cost in range a to d.

So why is this not applicable in **Chained Matrix Problem**?

Assume there is a set of matrix {x1, x2, ..., xn}

Obviously the cost of the multiplication in range b to c is smaller than the cost of the multiplication in range a to d cause, there is more element in range a to d than b to c.

Can somebody explain about this?

Comment: It's perfectly defined in your link and wrongly pasted (wrong def) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Relative Monotonicity can be in a higher dimensions as well .
Imagine a 2D plane where you hold the bottom right conrener and lift it such that we get `A[i-1][j] <= A[i][j] <= A[i][j+1]`.

If such monotonicity holds then we say that the problem space can be optimized using Knuth Optinimzaton.
ie `F[i][j] = min{F[i][k]+F[k+1][j]}+C[i][j] for k=i to j-1`,
then it can be optimized by traversing only `from k=P[i-1][j] to P[i][j+1]`
where `P[i][j]` is the point where `A[i][j]` is minimum.

Original problem need O(n^3) whereas due to the above monotonicity it can now be solved in O(n^2)

(Note: here there is no absolute monotonicity between any two elements, that's why I termed it as relative monotonicity, if two elements are such that one is to the south east of another then the south eastern element is greater than or equal to the other, such relationship is good enough for Knuth Optimization)